# Javascript clear text field on submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that utilizes the Jquery form plugin. When the form is submitted I need to clear a textfield on my page. When this Javascript is run I want it clear the Textfield after running the php page.

```
<script> 
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $("#glue").ajaxForm({url: 'scripts/glue.php', type: 'post'})
    }); 
</script>
```

This is my input field:

```
<input type="text" id="glueField" class="form-control" name="word" placeholder="Press enter to glue a word" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use this method from the jQuery Form plugin, which clears all text inputs, password inputs, etc. inside of your ajax form. Like this:

```
$("#glue").ajaxForm({url: 'scripts/glue.php', type: 'post'}, function() {
    // Callback for when post is completed
    $('#glue').clearForm();
});
```

More info [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not clear the input field.

Comment: +1 for using the same plugin

Comment: Thanks @user2310289. You could also try natively resetting the value with $('#glue')[0].reset();

Comment: $('#glue')[0].reset(); did nothing either :/

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$("#glue").ajaxForm({url: 'scripts/glue.php', type: 'post'}, function(){
  $('#glueField').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using inputs in that `#glue` then, after your ajax call, add this line would do the trick for you:

```
$('input').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. The jQuery form plugin has a method of doing this. I simply changed my jquery line to this:

```
$("#glue").ajaxForm({url: 'scripts/glue.php', type: 'post', clearForm: 'true'}, function() {
```

Adding:

```
clearForm: 'true'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery (textFieldId/class).val ("");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#glue").ajaxForm({url: 'scripts/glue.php', type: 'post', success: $("#glueField").val(''))})
```

You can do it like this. Set an empty string to the respective field on success.

Comment: Fix your code please.

Comment: fixed it. Was missing a comma right?

Comment: You have extra `'` after `$("#glueField")`

Comment: Hm. This rendered the form unsuable, now it redicects to the action page instead of using ajax. Don't know why though.